# No funciona el envio de correo de redis con laravel en mi servidor

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-6, redis

Hace unos días realice una actualización de versiones de laravel de la 5 a la 6.
Después de esto el envió de correos dejo de funcionar, lo tengo con un contenedor de redis utilizando laradock.

Tengo las siguientes configuraciones de redis
config/database.php

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
```

.env

QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_PASSWORD=null

REDIS_PORT=6379

¿Que puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: Revisando la [guía de actualización](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#redis-default-client) encontré esto, que posiblemente esté relacionado  > El cliente Redis predeterminado ha cambiado de `predis` a `phpredis`. Para seguir usando predis, asegúrese de que la opción de configuración `redis.client` esté configurada en predis en su archivo de configuración `config/database.php`.

Comment: Si me fije en eso también, pero no, no funciona. Gracias